# Is there a SQL query to format date as YYYY, MM, DD?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I tried fetching date from table using date(column_name) which gives output:

```
2018-03-13
```

But is there a way to get the same result in the format

```
2018, 03, 13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You Can Use**

```
SELECT REPLACE(col_Name,'-',', ') FROM table_Name;
```

**Or**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(col_Name, '%Y, %m, %d') FROM table_Name;
```

**Example**

```
SELECT REPLACE('2018-03-13','-',', ')
```

**Output**

```
2018, 03, 13
```

**Live Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e80e77/6

Answer (score 4):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` method provided by mysql.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2018-03-13", "%Y, %m, %d");
```

Result:

```
2018, 03, 13
```

Answer (score 2):

There is.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2018-03-13", "%Y, %m, %d");
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp